WooCommerce Products Custom Dynamic Filters issue for Attributes, Brands and price
I'm trying to create a Woocommerce filter. Basicly everything works fine but there are some dynamic issues.
<?php

// Functie om gefilterde termen binnen de context van de huidige categorie op te halen
function get_filtered_terms($taxonomy, $product_ids, $tax_query) {
    if (empty($product_ids)) {
        return array(); // Geen producten, geen termen
    }

    // Termen ophalen die zijn gekoppeld aan de huidige product-ID's
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'object_ids' => $product_ids,
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ));

    // Termen specifiek binnen de huidige categorie context tellen
    $filtered_terms = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $term_count_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array_merge($tax_query, array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug,
                ),
            )),
            'fields' => 'ids',
        ));
        $term->count = $term_count_query->found_posts;
        $filtered_terms[] = $term;
    }

    return $filtered_terms;
}


function custom_filter_form_shortcode() {
    if (!is_product_category() && !is_tax('brand')) {
        return ''; // Alleen de filter tonen op categorie- en merkspecifieke pagina's
    }

    ob_start();

    // Huidige categorie of merk ophalen
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();

    // Filtervolgorde en zichtbaarheid van de instellingenpagina ophalen
    $filter_order = get_option('filter_order_' . $queried_object->term_id, 'price,brand,size');
    $filters_visibility = get_option('filters_visibility_' . $queried_object->term_id, array(
        'price' => 1,
        'brand' => 1,
        'size' => 1
    ));

    // Filtervolgorde verwerken
    $filter_order = explode(',', $filter_order);

    // Huidige product-ID's van de query ophalen (alle pagina's)
    $tax_query = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $queried_object->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $queried_object->slug,
        ),
    );

    // Merkenfilter toevoegen indien ingesteld
    if (isset($_GET['brand'])) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['brand'],
            'operator' => 'IN'
        );
    }

    // Maatfilter toevoegen indien ingesteld
    if (isset($_GET['size'])) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['size'],
            'operator' => 'IN'
        );
    }

    $total_product_ids = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    ));
    $product_ids = wp_list_pluck($total_product_ids->posts, 'ID');

    // Filteren van de termen met de huidige filters
    $brands = get_filtered_terms('brand', $product_ids, $tax_query);

    // Render de filtervorm
    ?>
    <div class="desktop-filter-container">
        <form method="get" action="" class="custom-filter-form">
            <div class="sort-dropdown">
                <label for="orderby">Sorteren op:</label>
                <select name="orderby" id="orderby" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                    <?php foreach ($orderby_options as $value => $label) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>" <?php selected($selected_orderby, $value); ?>><?php echo esc_html($label); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="filter-section">
                <h5>Prijs</h5>
                <div class="price-slider-container">
                </div>
                <div id="price-range"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Merk filter toevoegen -->
            <?php
            if (!empty($brands) && !is_wp_error($brands)) {
                echo '<div class="attribute-section">';
                echo '<h4 class="toggle-section" data-index="brand">Merk</h4>';
                echo '<div class="attribute-terms">';
                $term_count = 0;
                foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                    $checked = isset($_GET['brand']) && is_array($_GET['brand']) && in_array($brand->slug, $_GET['brand']) ? 'checked' : '';
                    if ($term_count < 5) {
                        echo '<label class="checkbox-label">';
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                        echo esc_html($brand->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $brand->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                        echo '</label>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<label class="checkbox-label more-terms" style="display:none;">';
                        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                        echo esc_html($brand->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $brand->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                        echo '</label>';
                    }
                    $term_count++;
                }
                if ($term_count > 5) {
                    echo '<span class="show-more">Toon meer</span>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            // Bestaande attributenfilters
            $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute->attribute_name);
                // Zichtbaarheid controleren voordat je weergeeft
                if (isset($filters_visibility[$taxonomy]) && $filters_visibility[$taxonomy]) {
                    // Gefilterde termen ophalen met product_ids en huidige tax_query
                    $terms = get_filtered_terms($taxonomy, $product_ids, $tax_query);

                    if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
                        echo '<div class="attribute-section">';
                        echo '<h4 class="toggle-section" data-index="' . $count . '">' . esc_html($attribute->attribute_label) . '</h4>';
                        echo '<div class="attribute-terms">';
                        $term_count = 0;
                        foreach ($terms as $term) {
                            $checked = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) && is_array($_GET[$taxonomy]) && in_array($term->slug, $_GET[$taxonomy]) ? 'checked' : '';
                            if ($term_count < 5) {
                                echo '<label class="checkbox-label">';
                                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                                echo esc_html($term->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $term->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                                echo '</label>';
                            } else {
                                echo '<label class="checkbox-label more-terms" style="display:none;">';
                                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                                echo esc_html($term->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $term->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                                echo '</label>';
                            }
                            $term_count++;
                        }
                        if ($term_count > 5) {
                            echo '<span class="show-more">Toon meer</span>';
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-filter-container">
        <button class="open-filters-btn">Filters</button>
        <div class="mobile-filters">
            <button class="close-filters-btn">&times;</button>
            <form method="get" action="" class="custom-filter-form">
                <div class="sort-dropdown">
                    <label for="orderby">Sorteren op:</label>
                    <select name="orderby" id="orderby" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <?php foreach ($orderby_options as $value => $label) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($value); ?>" <?php selected($selected_orderby, $value); ?>><?php echo esc_html($label); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="filter-section">
                    <h5>Prijs</h5>
                    <div class="price-slider-container">
                    </div>
                    <div id="price-range"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Merk filter toevoegen -->
                <?php
                $brands = get_filtered_terms('brand', $product_ids, $tax_query);

                if (!empty($brands) && !is_wp_error($brands)) {
                    echo '<div class="attribute-section">';
                    echo '<h4 class="toggle-section" data-index="brand">Merk</h4>';
                    echo '<div class="attribute-terms">';
                    $term_count = 0;
                    foreach ($brands as $brand) {
                        $checked = isset($_GET['brand']) && is_array($_GET['brand']) && in_array($brand->slug, $_GET['brand']) ? 'checked' : '';
                        if ($term_count < 5) {
                            echo '<label class="checkbox-label">';
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                            echo esc_html($brand->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $brand->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                            echo '</label>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<label class="checkbox-label more-terms" style="display:none;">';
                            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="brand[]" value="' . esc_attr($brand->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                            echo esc_html($brand->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $brand->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                            echo '</label>';
                        }
                        $term_count++;
                    }
                    if ($term_count > 5) {
                        echo '<span class="show-more">Toon meer</span>';
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                // Bestaande attributenfilters
                $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
                    $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute->attribute_name);
                    // Zichtbaarheid controleren voordat je weergeeft
                    if (isset($filters_visibility[$taxonomy]) && $filters_visibility[$taxonomy]) {
                        // Gefilterde termen ophalen met product_ids en huidige tax_query
                        $terms = get_filtered_terms($taxonomy, $product_ids, $tax_query);

                        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
                            echo '<div class="attribute-section">';
                            echo '<h4 class="toggle-section" data-index="' . $count . '">' . esc_html($attribute->attribute_label) . '</h4>';
                            echo '<div class="attribute-terms">';
                            $term_count = 0;
                            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                $checked = isset($_GET[$taxonomy]) && is_array($_GET[$taxonomy]) && in_array($term->slug, $_GET[$taxonomy]) ? 'checked' : '';
                                if ($term_count < 5) {
                                    echo '<label class="checkbox-label">';
                                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                                    echo esc_html($term->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $term->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                                    echo '</label>';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<label class="checkbox-label more-terms" style="display:none;">';
                                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . esc_attr($taxonomy) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr($term->slug) . '" ' . $checked . '>';
                                    echo esc_html($term->name) . ' <span class="attribute-count">(' . $term->count . ')</span>'; // Termnaam en aantal tonen
                                    echo '</label>';
                                }
                                $term_count++;
                            }
                            if ($term_count > 5) {
                                echo '<span class="show-more">Toon meer</span>';
                            }
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            $count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <button type="submit" class="apply-filters-btn">Bevestig filters</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            function filterProducts() {
                var selectedBrands = [];
                var selectedSizes = [];

                $('.checkbox-label input[name="brand[]"]:checked').each(function() {
                    selectedBrands.push($(this).val());
                });

                $('.checkbox-label input[name="size[]"]:checked').each(function() {
                    selectedSizes.push($(this).val());
                });

                $('.products .product').each(function() {
                    var product = $(this);
                    var productPrice = parseFloat(product.data('price'));
                    var productBrands = product.data('brands').split(',');
                    var productSizes = product.data('sizes').split(',');

                    var showProduct = true;

                    if (selectedBrands.length > 0 && !selectedBrands.some(r => productBrands.includes(r))) {
                        showProduct = false;
                    }

                    if (selectedSizes.length > 0 && !selectedSizes.some(r => productSizes.includes(r))) {
                        showProduct = false;
                    }

                    if (productPrice < minPrice || productPrice > maxPrice) {
                        showProduct = false;
                    }

                    if (showProduct) {
                        product.show();
                    } else {
                        product.hide();
                    }
                });
            }

            // Automatically filter the products when a checkbox is clicked
            $(document).on('change', '.checkbox-label input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });

            // Submit form when user changes the input fields for min and max price
            $('#min_price, #max_price').on('change keyup', function() {
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
            });


            // Mobiele filter toggle
            $('.open-filters-btn').on('click', function() {
                $('.mobile-filters').addClass('active');
            });

            $('.close-filters-btn, .apply-filters-btn').on('click', function() {
                $('.mobile-filters').removeClass('active');
            });

            // Initialize filtering
            filterProducts();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); // Zorg ervoor dat deze regel correct is afgesloten
}
add_shortcode('custom_filter_form', 'custom_filter_form_shortcode'); // Zorg ervoor dat deze regel correct is afgesloten

function apply_custom_filters($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && (is_product_category() || is_shop() || is_tax('brand'))) {
        // Huidige categorie of merk ophalen
        $queried_object = get_queried_object();
        $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
        $slug = $queried_object->slug;


        // Filteren op attributen
        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $slug,
            ),
        );

        $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $taxonomy_name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute->attribute_name);
            if (isset($_GET[$taxonomy_name])) {
                $tax_query[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy_name,
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $_GET[$taxonomy_name],
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                );
            }
        }

        // Filteren op merk
        if (isset($_GET['brand'])) {
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'brand',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_GET['brand'],
                'operator' => 'IN'
            );
        }

        // Stel het aantal producten per pagina in
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 16);
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'apply_custom_filters');

function load_custom_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-slider-css', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_scripts');

function enqueue_sortable_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-admin-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-admin.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-sortable'), false, true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_sortable_script');

add_action('admin_menu', 'custom_filters_menu');
function custom_filters_menu() {
    add_submenu_page(
        'edit.php?post_type=product',
        'Filters',
        'Filters',
        'manage_options',
        'custom-filters',
        'custom_filters_page'
    );
}

function custom_filters_page() {
    // Get product categories
    $categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><?php _e('Product Filters Settings', 'textdomain'); ?></h1>
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php settings_fields('custom_filters_settings_group'); ?>
            <?php do_settings_sections('custom_filters_settings_group'); ?>
            <div class="form-table">
                <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
                    <div class="category-section">
                        <h2><?php echo esc_html($category->name); ?></h2>
                        <div>
                            <?php
                            $filter_order = get_option('filter_order_' . $category->term_id, 'price,brand,size');
                            $filters_visibility = get_option('filters_visibility_' . $category->term_id, array(
                                'price' => 1,
                                'brand' => 1,
                                'size' => 1
                            ));

                            // Ensure filters_visibility is an array
                            if (!is_array($filters_visibility)) {
                                $filters_visibility = array(
                                    'price' => 1,
                                    'brand' => 1,
                                    'size' => 1
                                );
                            }

                            $attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
                            ?>
                            <ul class="sortable" id="sortable_<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>">
                                <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute) : 
                                    $taxonomy = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attribute->attribute_name);
                                    ?>
                                    <li id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="filters_visibility_<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>[<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>]" value="1" <?php checked(isset($filters_visibility[$taxonomy]) ? $filters_visibility[$taxonomy] : 0, 1); ?> />
                                            <?php echo esc_html($attribute->attribute_label); ?>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <input type="hidden" class="filter-order-input" name="filter_order_<?php echo esc_attr($category->term_id); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr($filter_order); ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.sortable').sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                    $(this).siblings('.filter-order-input').val(order);
                }
            });

            $('.sortable').disableSelection();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('admin_init', 'register_custom_filters_settings');
function register_custom_filters_settings() {
    $categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        register_setting('custom_filters_settings_group', 'filter_order_' . $category->term_id);
        register_setting('custom_filters_settings_group', 'filters_visibility_' . $category->term_id, array(
            'type' => 'array',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'custom_sanitize_filters_visibility'
        ));
    }
}

function custom_sanitize_filters_visibility($input) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        $output[$key] = intval($value);
    }
    return $output;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_tax_query', 10, 2);
function custom_product_query_tax_query($tax_query, $query) {
    if (isset($_GET['pa_diagonaal-van-het-scherm-cm'])) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_diagonaal-van-het-scherm-cm',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $_GET['pa_diagonaal-van-het-scherm-cm'],
            'operator' => 'IN',
        );
    }
    return $tax_query;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_layered_nav_counts', 'custom_layered_nav_counts', 10, 2);
function custom_layered_nav_counts($counts, $taxonomy) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Get the current category or brand
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $current_term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

    // Get the current filtered product IDs
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $queried_object->taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $current_term_id,
            ),
            WC()->query->get_main_tax_query(),
        ),
        'meta_query' => WC()->query->get_meta_query(),
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ));

    $product_ids = $query->posts;

    if (!empty($product_ids)) {
        // Loop through each term in the taxonomy and count the products
        foreach ($taxonomy->get_terms() as $term) {
            $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.ID)
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
                INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
                WHERE p.post_type = 'product'
                AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                AND tt.taxonomy = %s
                AND tt.term_id = %d
                AND p.ID IN (" . implode(',', $product_ids) . ")
            ", $taxonomy->taxonomy, $term->term_id));

            // Add the new count to the array
            $counts[$term->term_id] = $count;
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($taxonomy->get_terms() as $term) {
            $counts[$term->term_id] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $counts;
}
?>

You can test it here:
https://waaaauw.be/product-categorie/tv-video-en-thuisbioscoop-tv-s/
Issue describe
Selecting filter attribute
Issue dynamic count of attributes

As you can see when I select for example 106,7 cm (4) it should say for "brands" (this is a taxonomy and not an attribute):
Panasonic (1)
LG (3)

Attributes should be dynamic aswell for example energie class keeps saying:
A (2)
D (8)
E (109)
F (164)
G (202)

It should say
E (4) - EXAMPLE

So the counter doesn't work dynamicly. I'm pretty much stuck here because I can't see what I have done wrong.
When you press on the "brand" the filters remove aswell:
Brand removes filters
You can test it live on this provided link.

So far no solution has been found.

I have the idea because $brand is looking for a page the same way as the catergory does it doesn't show up correctly. It should I geuss say that brand is a part of category if I get it right.

Problem fix found:
// Altijd de productcategorie ID ophalen (bijvoorbeeld via een URL-parameter of andere logica)
if (isset($_GET['product_cat'])) {
    $current_product_cat_slug = sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']);
    $current_product_cat = get_term_by('slug', $current_product_cat_slug, 'product_cat');
    if ($current_product_cat) {
        $current_product_cat_id = $current_product_cat->term_id;
    }
} else {
    // Als er geen specifieke categorie is gekozen, gebruik dan de huidige term ID
    $current_product_cat_id = $current_term_id;
}

// Debug log om de gebruikte productcategorie ID te controleren
error_log('Geselecteerde productcategorie ID: ' . $current_product_cat_id);

// Gebruik altijd de productcategorie ID om de zichtbaarheid van de attributenfilters op te halen
if ($current_product_cat_id) {
    $filters_visibility = get_option('filters_visibility_' . $current_product_cat_id, array());

    // Testwaarde toevoegen om te controleren of de optie correct wordt opgehaald
    if (empty($filters_visibility)) {
        // Voeg een testwaarde toe
        $filters_visibility = array('pa_diagonaal-van-het-scherm-cm' => 1, 'pa_energieklasse' => 1);
        update_option('filters_visibility_' . $current_product_cat_id, $filters_visibility);
        error_log('Testwaarde ingesteld voor productcategorie ' . $current_product_cat_id);
    }

    error_log('Filters zichtbaarheid voor productcategorie ' . $current_product_cat_id . ': ' . print_r($filters_visibility, true));
} else {
    $filters_visibility = array();
}

// Controleer of de filters_visibility een array is en niet leeg
if (is_array($filters_visibility) && !empty($filters_visibility)) {
    error_log('Filters zichtbaarheid (eindresultaat): ' . print_r($filters_visibility, true));
} else {
    error_log('Filters zichtbaarheid is leeg of geen array voor productcategorie ' . $current_product_cat_id);
    $filters_visibility = array();
}

// Zorg ervoor dat de filters_visibility een array is
if (!is_array($filters_visibility)) {
    $filters_visibility = array();
}

// Debug log om de definitieve filters zichtbaarheid te controleren
error_log('Definitieve filters zichtbaarheid: ' . print_r($filters_visibility, true));

This code made the change:
// Testwaarde toevoegen om te controleren of de optie correct wordt opgehaald
    if (empty($filters_visibility)) {
        // Voeg een testwaarde toe
        $filters_visibility = array('pa_diagonaal-van-het-scherm-cm' => 1, 'pa_energieklasse' => 1);
        update_option('filters_visibility_' . $current_product_cat_id, $filters_visibility);
        error_log('Testwaarde ingesteld voor productcategorie ' . $current_product_cat_id);
    }

